# Difference between lowest_layer() and next_layer() from Boost Asio SSL Stream

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

The documentation doesn't seem to tell much: [lowest_layer()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/lowest_layer.html), [next_layer()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/next_layer.html).

What is the difference between them and when to use each?

Comment: SSL socket derives from a non-SSL socket. Asio creates an SSL socket by wrapping it in a container that provides some additional functionality and that intercepts some activities by adding an SSL flavour to them. Code using such an SSL socket will need to use `next_layer()` to gain access to the underlying socket for some activities common to both SSL and non-SSL sockets. The call to the `lowest_layer` allows to you to call methods of the ordinary tcp socket such as `connect` or `accept`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer this, first thing to remember is that `boost::asio::ssl::stream` is a template class. Usually it look like `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>`. Thus is implemented using `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`. That will be **next_layer** for `boost::asio::ssl::stream`. On other side, **lowest_layer** is always will be a `basic_socket` (its described in the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/lowest_layer_type.html)).

Its little ambiguous especially when you see in the headers `tcp::socket` is typedef to `basic_stream_socket<Tcp>`, which is directly inherited from `basic_socket`. And.. In OOP terms you can say "next_layer IS the lowest_layer"..

But lets take another case where you create a `ssl::stream< MyOwnClass >`. In this case **next_layer** is `MyOwnClass`, which should control data reads/writes. And **lowest_layer** will be be whatever `MyOwnClass` will say in its typedef.

UPD: When to use each. Use **next_layer** for read/writes (you don't need this for SSL connection, but before starttls session its required). And use **lowest_layer** to control underlying socket.